# Laptop screen degradation?

Tags: display, macbook-pro

See the picture. This is not grease from finger tips. I tried to clean it but nothing happened. Then I realised it was the screen itself. When I work with the laptop, I don't notice it. Laptop is four years old, late 2015 Macbook Pro Retina. Besides this the screen has a flicker once or twice a day, a white flashing bar on the screen.

What is this, and does this mean that the end (of this screen) is near?

[image: Macbook top left screen corner degradation]

Comment: I believe there's a sticky at Apple Care about that kind of issue, and even though your MBP is four-years old, you might get into the program for a free or not-too-costly repair. Contact Apple Care, give them the info they ask about your MBP (About this Mac > More details), and they'll tell you what they can do for you. See here for more details: https://9to5mac.com/2017/02/24/retina-macbook-display-staingate/

Comment: Not a Mac expert, but this looks like my coated eye glasses - I wonder if there is a UV/oleophobic/hydrophobic coating that is wearing off? Does the part of the surface "playing up" have a tactile texture to it?

Comment: Thanks. I contacted Apple Support, and they said I need to go to a service point nearby, let them check it. They can tell me if that program is still in place and what the options are. I'm afraid my mac is too old, but it's worth the effort.